# Could not resolve placeholder property during integration test

Tags: spring

I am doing integration test using spring.

I have AppA. This does has properties file to load bean property. For unit testing, i have created AppATestContext and added this properties file using @propertySource. Unit testing of this AppA works fine.

I have included AppA-test.jar into BigApp. I am trying write unit test for BigApp. I have included AppATestContext into the BigApp test context. Now when i run bigApp Unit test, i am getting "Could not resolve placeholder error".

Why is that, AppAtestContext should have loaded the bean with the properties correct? Where i am missing.

At the same time, if i include AppA's properties file into the BigApp's placeholderconfigurer, it is working.

**UPDATE**

AppAtestContext.java

```
@PropertySource("app.properties")
class AppTestContext{
//propertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean declaration.
}
```

BigAppTestContext.xml

```
<bean class="AppAtestContext.java"/>
```

BigAppTest.java

```
@ContextHierarchy{@ContextConfiguration={BigAppTestContext.xml})
class SomeTest{
}
```

This test doesnot put app.properties into the bean defined in AppA project.

Comment: Add @Configurable in your context bean or instead <context:property-placeholder location="app.properties"> in your xml

Comment: But without adding your suggesting, all unit test in AppA are working fine.

Comment: Where is your app.properties? I have the feeling it's inside the .JAR and your test can't access it. Try adding classpath:/ before app.properties.

Comment: Yes, it is inside AppA.jar. I think i have path correctly, because AppA's unit test is running fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide anycode, I'll provide a generic answer...

All my tests run with this configuration, to make sure the isolation is perfect :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Configurable
@ImportResource({ "classpath:/testContext-basic.xml" })

@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyTest.class, AnyDependancy.class })
```

Make sure to include your test in the context, so Spring scans the beans.

testContext-basic is just :

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Then you get to Mock your beans with :

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Bean
public MyMock getMyMock() {
    return Mockito.mock(MyMock.class);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with some code snippet. Let me know if you got me.