# Multiple Configurations In Spring Junit Test Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

We are using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` with `ContextConfiguration` annotation, for example, testing a front end controller:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class FrontEndControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private FrontEndController frontEndController;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(frontEndController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDirectToSomeView() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("someView"));
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class FrontEndControllerTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public FrontEndController defaultController() {
            return // init controller
        }

        @Bean
        public SomeConfigObject config() {
            return // some config
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to add another test with a different configuration into the same the class. For example, inject a mock with a failing database operation, or or or.

Is it possible add another test like this (I know, will not compile):

```
@Test
@ContextConfiguration(/* My other configuration */)
public void shouldDoSomeOtherStuff_InvalidConfiguration() {
      // ...
}
```

In Spring 4 it is not possible because `ContextConfiguration` can only be declared as annotation in front of the class. Is there something like this in Spring 4? Do you recommend to try another approach?

Comment: You can't. You have to create another test class with it's own context.

Comment: Do you recommend another approach?

Comment: I can point you to another answer I gave which gives a way to configure a perfect test isolation (ignore the question, my answer doesn't really match) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788771/could-not-resolve-placeholder-property-during-integration-test/33788901#33788901

Comment: Why can't you define the mock behavior in the test itself?

Comment: I could not until I used `DirtiesContext`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: The problem is that I want to get new mocks for every test and I want to modify them before I perform `mockMvc.perform(get("/"))`. Therefore you can use `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` annotation. Here is my code:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class FrontEndControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private FrontEndController frontEndController;

    @Autowired
    private SomeConfigObject config;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(frontEndController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDirectToSomeView() throws Exception {
        // mock valid behaviour of config

        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("someView"));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotDirectToSomeView_InvalidConfiguration() throws Exception {
        // mock invalid behaviour of config

        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError())
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class FrontEndControllerTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public FrontEndController defaultController() {
            return // init controller
        }

        @Bean
        public SomeConfigObject config() {
            return mock(SomeConfigObject.class);
        }
    }
}
```